# How to write incoming frames to file without touching in ffmpeg?

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I am able to read frames from av_open_input_file and decode and reencode it with another codec and save to file.

Now, I want the same thing, except i don't want to decode or reencode. I want to do av_interleaved_write_frame on the just read frame to file. To do this, i need to set AVOutputFormat

AVOutputFormat *fmt;
fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, filename, NULL);

However, i can not supply a filename, because it is a remote stream. So, is there any way to generate AVOutputFormat from the current AVFormatContext which already reads input frames? So i can write the same frame to the output file from any part of it (not necessarily from the beginning) in the correct way.

To summarize: I need to write the just read frame to the file without decoding and reencoding. (I will open that file another time to be able to play that file)

Any ideas?